# Can't build FBParseUtilsV4 after cocoapods install when use_frameworks is enabled

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods, facebook-ios-sdk

Install the following Podfile in an otherwise empty project:

```
use_frameworks! 
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
```

Xcode reports three compilation errors:

`/Users/benpackard/Cocoa/PodsTest/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKLoginKit.FBSDKLoginButton'`

`/Users/benpackard/Cocoa/PodsTest/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginConstants.h:21:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKLoginKit.FBSDKLoginConstants'`

`/Users/benpackard/Cocoa/PodsTest/Pods/ParseFacebookUtilsV4/ParseFacebookUtils/Internal/PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.h:12:9: Could not build module 'FBSDKLoginKit'`

When the `use_frameworks!` option is removed from the Podfile, the project compiles without issue.

I would like to know the root cause of this issue (presumably some issue in the pod?) and possible workarounds.

Comment: Here's my open bug report https://github.com/ParsePlatform/ParseFacebookUtils-iOS/issues/2#issuecomment-147071071

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end
```

at the end of your podfile.

Then, via terminal : pod install

Though, I got a semantic issue after that : Unknown type name 'FBSDK_EXTERN'

EDIT : Well, I just removed FBSDK_EXTERN in every file (I'm not sure it's the good way though :p )